# Angular 2 HTTP (JSON)

Tags: angular2

Есть в сети джейсон файл. (структура проще некуда (id:10, name:Jon).
С помощью http на ангуляре 2-ом хочу получить этот файл и хотя бы первую строку вывести в {{result}}

Как это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 Можно вот так:
getLocation() {
    return this.http.request('/app/admin/users/driver/services/json/location.json')
        .map(res => res.json());
}
```

а в контроллере

```
 service.getLocation().subscribe(
 res => {

  console.log(res)
})
```

Обновлено

```
import {HttpService} from 'path/to/httpService'; //без расширения
 ...
@Component({
... 
template: `<p>{{ result.name }}</p>
           <p>{{ result.age }}</p>`,
providers: [Http, HttpService]
})
...
private result:any = {name: '', age:''};
constructor(private service:HttpService) {
    this.getData();
}

getData() {
   let self = this;
   this.service.getLocation()
          .subscribe(res => {
          self.result = res;
          console.log(res); 
         });
}
```

Пример по [ссылке](https://github.com/pictaile/angular2-example)

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54165/discussion-on-answer-by-konstantin-okhotnick-angular-2-http-json).

Answer (score 1):

Для вывода елементов в html используй директиву ***ngFor**:

**template.html**

```
<tr *ngFor="let element of elements">
  <td>{{ element.name }}</td>
</td>
```

Чтобы получить файл, отправь GET-запрос

**some.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'sd-home',
  templateUrl: 'template.html'
})

@Injectable()
export class SomeComponent implements OnInit {
  public elements: any;

  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private http: Http
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(){ this.getInfo(); }

  getInfo(){
    let resp = this.index();
    resp.subscribe(data => {this.elements = data.elements;});
  }

  index() {
    return this.http.get('http://example.com')
      .map((res: Response) => res.json())
  }
}
```

Comment: а чего оно ругается http://prntscr.com/ecbzr2 ?

Comment: спасибо, что дополнил, осталаось только две ошибки )))
http://prntscr.com/ecc5li
очень буду благодарен, второй день разбираюсь и никак

Comment: и template.html хотелось бы глянуть

Comment: @ЯрославВолодимирович Я для примера написал ссылку, где файл брать, http://example.com. Понятное дело что оно там ничего не находит

Comment: я не об этом, я о том, что у методе

 getInfo() {
    let resp = this.index();
    resp.subscribe(data => { this.elements = data.elements; });
  }

нет data

Comment: а здесь 

index() {
    return this.http.get('http://example.com')
      .map((res: Response) => res.json())
  }

после return this.http.get('http://example.com') нет .map есть subscribe